# UIButton doesn't show image

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit

I have a `UITableViewCell` that I'm adding five `UIButtons` to. I programmatically create the buttons, add an action, and an image. The buttons are placed in the correct spot, the action works, and the tag is set, but they are clear. The images do not show.

This is what I'm using to create one of the buttons and add them to the cell, this code is in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` :

```
if ([[self.compCompletion objectForKey:@"Key" isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(11, 6, 21, 21);
            button.tag = 1;
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeCompStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp-Completed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
        }
        else {
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(11, 6, 21, 21);
            button.tag = 1;
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeCompStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp-Uncompleted.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
        }
```

I've tried adding: `[button setEnabled:YES];`, `[button setHidden:NO];`, and `[button setNeedsDislpay];` to the process with no luck. How do I get the button to display the image?

**EDIT:**
My image exists, the `UIImage` created, and I can pull the `UIImage` out of the `UIButton` and save it to a file. I've gone through each property of the `UIButton` that controls appearance and changed them. I also tried an empty `UIButton` of type `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` and `UIButtonTypeAddContact`. I'm now believe that this has something to do with the `UITableViewCell` not liking `UIButtons`, or how I'm adding the `UIButton` to the `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Are you sure the image names are correct (inc. case) and the image files are included in your project?

Comment: Yes the image names are correct, I use the same images for an accessory view in a different UITableView

Comment: Are you sure that cell is showing the button? Try setting it's bacgroundColor to make sure...

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that you have checked your project as Target Membership when copying the files. It helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was dragging the images into an images.xcassets file that was part of a pod, NOT the main project. It showed fine in the storyboard, but did not appear in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your images exist and are imported. Also it looks to me that besides of the image name the code is identical. A bit cleaner as:

```
UIImage *buttonImage;
if ([[self.compCompletion objectForKey:@"Key" isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
    buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp-Completed.png"];
} else {
    buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp-Uncompleted.png"];
}

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(11, 6, 21, 21);
button.tag = 1;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeCompStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: The images exist and are imported, I use the same images in a different UITableView and they work there. (But I am not putting them in a UIButton.)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer: Once the image was in assets.xcassets then I needed to include it in the "copy bundle resources" areas of the Build Phases part of the Target.  Then I also had to set a transparent color so that it wasn't obscured.

project->targets->build phases->copy bundle resources-> "+" -> "add other"->select the image in the finder.

Answer (score 0):

Can it definitely find the images? Are they included in the project?

Just to test, try using an image you've already used somewhere else instead of Comp-Completed.png - if that works, you know that the problem is that it's failing to find that file.

Comment: I use a different image, and it still does not work. I also double checked the image names, and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage * normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp-Uncompleted.png"];
UIImage * selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp-Completed.png"];

UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
button.frame = CGRectMake(11, 6, 21, 21);
button.tag = 1;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeCompStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

if ([[self.compCompletion objectForKey:@"Key" isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
    button.selected = YES;
} else {
    button.selected = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but I came across the same problem and it was due to `isHidden` and `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to values to hide the button.

You have to be careful when to set them to `YES` or `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for answer, double check if you have copied the image to `Assets.xcassets` in project directory not in pods directory.

Second I used render as original image in `Assets.xcassets` image properties